# Django Set foreign key to parent value on delete

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have a model, `Location` with a self-referential foreign key. On deletion of a location's parent, I want to set its `parent_id` to its grandparent's ID, but not surprisingly, the following throws the error `name 'parent' is not defined`:

```
class Location(Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', models.SET(parent))
```

If I were to delete `Colorado` from this table:

```
| id | name     | parent_id |
|----|----------|-----------|
| 1  | USA      | NULL      |
| 2  | Canada   | NULL      |
| 3  | Colorado | 1         |
| 4  | Utah     | 1         |
| 5  | Denver   | 3         |
| 6  | Boulder  | 3         |
```

I would want the result to look like this:

```
| id | name     | parent_id |
|----|----------|-----------|
| 1  | USA      | NULL      |
| 2  | Canada   | NULL      |
| 4  | Utah     | 1         |
| 5  | Denver   | 1         |
| 6  | Boulder  | 1         |
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error is expected, the `models.SET` can take a callable but it accepts no arguments hence problem remain as we don't have access to object being deleted, what you are trying to achieve can be handled by [post_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-delete) signal:

```
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Location,
          dispatch_uid='some.unique.string.id.for.location.delete')
def location_post_delete_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    parent = instance.parent
    Location.objects.filter(parent_id=instance.id).update(parent=parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aamir Adnan's answer didn't work fo me, because at post_delete signal moment instance has no id attribute already(I guess). So I used pre_delete

```
# when a category is deleted, switchs its childrens parent attr to its own parent (or None)
@receiver(pre_delete,
          sender=Category,
          dispatch_uid='delete_category')
def category_post_delete_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    new_parent = instance.parent if instance.parent else None
    Category.objects.filter(parent_id=instance.id).update(parent=new_parent)
```

also I had to set on_delete to DO_NOTHING so it won't discard changes that pre_delete has just made.

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self',
          on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, # handled via Category's pre_delete signal
          verbose_name=_('parent'),
          related_name='child_categories',
          blank=True,
          null=True)
```